# Error while using pg:push to a Heroku PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, command-line-interface, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to push a local PostgreSQL database to one I've created on a Heroku app. To set up the Heroku database, I ran `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev -a jasons-react-jobly-app`, where `jasons-react-jobly-app` is the name of my Heroku app.

Then I ran `heroku pg:push jobly DATABASE_URL -a jasons-react-jobly-app`, where `jobly` is the name of my local database.

This throws the below error:

```
heroku-cli: Pushing jobly ---> postgresql-animate-30221
                case
------------------------------------
 0.9992547478473790.999254747847379
(1 row)

 !    Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

The error looks like an error that JavaScript throws when it tries to read properties of an undefined object or something, but I'm not sure where that would be happening in this database push. The app runs completely fine on my local machine with no errors. There is no `case` column in any of my database tables, so I'm not sure where that number is coming from either.

Also, if I check my Heroku config variables with `heroku config`, I see:

```
DATABASE_URL: postgres://iqawqkjfiybndd:c3e921131c239ccd6c880ad4b601deeaa4558339a90ebedc562a5575c9099f42@ec2-54-156-85-145.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dul2u6r13aq5i
```

So I know the database exists.

Any help with solving this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the name of the DB that you see attached to the heroku app on heroku dashboard.

At this url [https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/{put-your-app-name-here}/resources](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/%7Bput-your-app-name-here%7D/resources)
To get all app names in heroku cli do heroku apps and you will know which app's DB name you want from its dashboard.

Once you have the name of the DB (it will look like this "postgresql-pointy-81624")

use that name in the command to push local db to that db on heroku .

Here are steps to make sure everything works correctly
1- Check the connectivity to the heroku db first by doing

```
heroku pg:psql postgresql-[somedb name as found above] --app {your-app-name}
```

2- If it says to reset the DB and you can afford to reset then reset it using

```
heroku pg:reset -a {your-app-name}
```

3- Lastly do the migration of DB using this command

```
heroku pg:push jobly postgresql-[db name found above] -a {your-app-name}
```

if everything works as expected you will see this message

```
heroku-cli: Pushing complete.
```